# html5 photo capture with smartphone camera, image is rotated CW

Tags: html, image, capture

I test html5 features in mobile browsers(FF and Chrome). I want to capture image using 
`< input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`.

I created a handler for "change" event of `< input />` and I use it to get file data(name and content), to do that I use approach described in this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. After that I display content of photo in `< img />` by img.src=content. The problem is that when I take photo with device camera its rotated 90 degree and when I select img from device hard-drive its ok (its not rotated).

I have this problem in both FF and Chrome(Android device). I have not tested this case in other browsers/devices.

I'll be really greatful for any help.

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the EXIF data on the picture and rotate appropriately based on the orientation of how the user was taking the picture.

Other's have tackled this problem already and you can see a sample through https://github.com/gokercebeci/canvasResize as an example.